# React app won't load static files in production

Tags: reactjs, docker, webpack, create-react-app, amazon-ecs

I have created a small React app using `npx create-react-app` that I'm trying to host using AWS ECS/EC2.

Now, it runs perfectly fine locally from a Docker container but when I deploy the exact same Docker container to ECS it seems it's not serving the static files. I can see that it loads index.html but when it tries to load the js and css files it throws this error:

```
503 Service Temporarily Unavailable
```

My Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM node:19.2.0

ADD package-lock.json package.json /tmp/
WORKDIR /tmp
RUN npm ci
RUN npm install -g serve

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app && cd /usr/src/app && ln -s /tmp/node_modules

COPY . /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

RUN npm run build

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["serve", "-s", "build", "-l", "3000"]
```

I have toyed around with the `homepage` setting in package.json. It's currently set to `.` but it doesn't seem to make any difference.

**EDIT 1:**
The URL to my app is: `http://****.eu-north-1.elb.amazonaws.com/`
That will load index.html. The js file that is not loaded is in `http://****.eu-north-1.elb.amazonaws.com/static/js/main.e19b6f39.js`

**EDIT 2:**
There are no error sin the ECS logs and the load balancer's target group is healthy.

My listener rule is defined in cfn like this (Path = '/'):

```
 ListenerRule:
    Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::ListenerRule
    Properties:
      ListenerArn: !Ref Listener
      Priority: 1
      Conditions:
        - Field: path-pattern
          Values:
            - !Ref Path
      Actions:
        - TargetGroupArn: !Ref TargetGroup
          Type: forward
```

I'm kinda new to AWS. My CFN template is based on this one provided by AWS themselves but with very minor modifications: https://github.com/aws-samples/ecs-refarch-cloudformation

Comment: It would be helpful to see the URL of the index.html file which works, and the URL of at least one of the files that is not working. Since index.html is also a static file, your server is serving up one static file without issues. My guess is there is a hostname setting which needs to be updated in your server's configuration for it to work when it isn't running on `localhost`.

Comment: Updated the description with this info. Please see above.

Comment: Do you see any errors in the ECS container log? Are the targets in the Load Balancer's target group showing as Healthy? Do you have any listeners defined in the load balancer with custom routing rules?

Comment: Thanks for your input @MarkB. Updated the description with the requested details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got this working thanks to @MarkB drawing my attention to the AWS ELB listener rule.

The solution was to add a new listener rule for the path `/static/*` and forward these requests to the correct target group. Works like a charm :)